# Postgres : pg_restore/pg_dump everything EXCEPT the table id's for a table

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
pg_dump -a -O -t my_table my_db > my_data_to_import.sql
```

What I really want is to be able to import/export just the data without causing conflicts with my autoid field or overwriting existing data.

Maybe I'm thinking about the whole process wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-copy.html) with column list to dump and restore just data from one table. For example:

```
COPY my_table (column1, column2, ...) TO 'yourdumpfilepath';
COPY my_table (column1, column2, ...) FROM 'yourdumpfilepath';
```

OID is one of the [system columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html). For example it is not included in `SELECT * FROM my_table` (you need to use `SELECT oid,* FROM my_table`). OID is not the same as ordinary id column created along with other columns in [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html). Not every table has OID column. Check [default_with_oids](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS) option. If it's set to off, then probalby you don't have OID column in your table, but even if so, then you can still create table with OID using `WITH OIDS` option. It's recommended not to use OID as table's column (that's why default_with_oids is set to off prior to PostgreSQL 8.1).

Comment: And to import/export that data without the objects id can I use the OID switch?

Comment: @Paperino: Yes, there is OIDS boolean option for COPY.

Comment: Is OID the same thing as what I'm trying to exclude? I.d. for a table Books, my id field is 'id'? Do all columns have to be defined manually?

Answer (score 3):

```
pg_dump --insert -t TABLENAME DBNAME > fc.sql
       cat fc.sql | sed -e 's/VALUES [(][0-9][0-9],/VALUES (/g'|sed -e 's/[(]id,/(/g' > fce.sql
       psql -f fce.sql DBNAME
```

This dumps the table with columns into fc.sql then uses sed to remove the id, and the value associated with it